# Como passar um objeto por parâmetro no java para o JavaReports?

Tags: java, spring, jasper-reports, jasper, jaspersoft-studio

Boa noite galera, estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação, onde tem muitos atributos em uma classe, na qual, sera a fonte de dados para alguns campos no relatório jasper, tentei fazer da seguinte forma.

Projeto de exemplo...

1- Criei o código Java passando o objeto PRODUTO preenchido.

```
public void exportarPdfTeste(String code, HttpServletResponse response) {
    response.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_PDF_VALUE);
    response.setHeader("content-disposition", "inline; filename=relatorio-" + code + ".pdf");
    var funcionario = repository.findById(1L);

    try {
        this.addParams("NOME", funcionario.get().getNome());
        this.addParams("SALARIO", funcionario.get().getSalario());
        this.addParams("IMAGEM_DIRETORIO", JASPER_DIRECTORY_IMAGES);
        this.addParams("PRODUTO", new Produto("Carro", "Verde"));
        File file = ResourceUtils.getFile(JASPER_DIRECTORY.concat(code).concat(JASPER_SUFIXO));
        JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(file.getAbsolutePath(), params, connection);
        JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfStream(jasperPrint, response.getOutputStream());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

2 - No jasper criei 1 Parâmetro chamado `PRODUTO` e esse parâmetro é do tipo `com.mballem.curso.jasper.spring.entity.Produto` que é o caminho da classe dentro da minha aplicação spring.
[Parâmetro criado](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RO1jV.png)

3 - Porém na hora que eu tento dar um preview no relatório ele mostra os seguintes erros:
[Foto do erro no jasper](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7B70r.png)

4 - Esta é minha estrutura de pacotes na aplicação Spring: [Estrutura de pastas spring](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jyz0q.png)

Alguém sabe como resolver este problema? Se estou fazendo da forma correta, se a classe está sendo referenciada corretamente, porque não basta apenas colocar o parâmetro dentro das band e acessar pelos métodos Getters, ele pede a classe, mas quando referencio a classe, da este problema.

Esse é o codigo xml do jasper:

```
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 6.20.5.final using JasperReports Library version 6.20.5-3efcf2e67f959db3888d79f73dde2dbd7acb4f8e  -->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="teste2" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="d90ede5a-e64d-4a2d-ad47-4ec741f63895">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.report.description" value=""/>
    <import value="com.example.demo.*"/>
    <parameter name="cliente" class="com.example.demo.Cliente"/>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="cliente" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="nome" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <title>
        <band height="79" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="30" uuid="d568076f-37dd-47af-b60b-786e630b77f0"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{cliente}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </title>
    <pageHeader>
        <band height="35" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </pageHeader>
    <columnHeader>
        <band height="61" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </columnHeader>
    <columnFooter>
        <band height="45" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </columnFooter>
    <pageFooter>
        <band height="54" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </pageFooter>
    <summary>
        <band height="42" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </summary>
</jasperReport>
```

Comment: Se você conseguisse colocar o código do Jasper na pergunta facilitaria muito a análse.

Comment: @DiegoBorba adicionei o codigo xml a pergunta

Comment: Aonde está o parâmetro definido no XML?